# Android MediaRecorder in streaming

Tags: android, stream, red5, mediarecorder

Its possible to "stream" result of MediaRecorder?

The unique method i can see is mediaRecorder.setOutputFile that receives a FileDescriptor. So i can write the result to a File or send via socket to receiver.

I tried the second solution but  the result video is corrupted because is not "seekable" in stream.

The idea is to use the camera of android device to publish result to Red5.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it possible, there are many examples for that.
You can checkout [sipdroid](http://code.google.com/p/sipdroid/source/checkout) example.
Or even [Android IP camera](http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/source/checkout) which is much more simple.

Good Luck

Comment: [Here's](http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/source/browse/trunk/droidipcam/src/teaonly/projects/droidipcam/StreamingLoop.java) the relevant code. Seems to use a looped-back unix socket to get the data. Slightly hacky but not too much I think.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.
Here is the sample code with FileDescriptor and socket:

```
    socket = new Socket("192.168.1.234",8888);
    ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
```