# Livestreaming video from android device to server using openCV in android

Tags: android, opencv

My basic requirement is to stream live-video from android device to server. When I was researching about the same, I came across **OpenCV 2.4.6**. My question here is it possible to stream the video from android camera to server using **OpenCV 2.4.6** in android. If so can u please suggest how to go about it...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320691/android-mediarecorder-in-streaming might work

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can use **OpenCV** for streaming video from android device to PC.In my knowledge **OpenCV** is an **Image Processing library** that can be used to do process images and videos for,**Face recognition,Image compression,Augmented Reality etc.** My idea is to create a Socket between the Client device and the Server PC and pass the video through that socket just like what they did with this [spydroid application](https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/)