# Streaming Audio in FLAC or AMR_WB to the Google Speech API

Tags: android, kotlin, google-speech-api

I need to run the google speech api in somewhat low bandwidth environments.

Based on reading about best practices, it seems my best bet is to use the AMR_WB format.

However, the following code produces no exceptions, and I get no responses in the `onError(t: Throwable)` method, but the API is not returning any values at all in the `onNext(value: StreamingRecognizeResponse)` method.

If I change the format in `.setEncoding()` from `FLAC` or `AMR_WB` back to `LINEAR16` everything works fine.

AudioEmitter.kt

```
fun start(
            encoding: Int = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
            channel: Int = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            sampleRate: Int = 16000,
            subscriber: (ByteString) -> Unit
    )
```

MainActivity.kt

```
builder.streamingConfig = StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
        .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.AMR_WB)
                .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                .build())
        .setInterimResults(true)
        .setSingleUtterance(false)
        .build()
```

Comment: I think the problem may come from your `sampleRate` of `AudioEmitter`. Try to set it to 44100, 22050 or 11025 when the encoding type in streaming recognition is `FLAC`.

Comment: Maybe you can follow this official troubleshooting procedure? https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/support#troubleshooting  to define where the issue comes from.

Comment: @aminography I've messed with those settings, unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: @Bsquare Looked at those many times. Have tried every possible combination of settings I can find, and still no luck. It looks like both here and on the cloud-speech-discuss forum the team is completely disengaged.

Comment: Did you try converting your sound file in FLAC or something else, just to check if it is a key in your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Google won't recognize your data because you tell it the data is in *FLAC* or *AMR_WB* format, while you keep passing raw, uncompressed audio chunks that `AudioRecord.read()` produces.

Now, in order to make it work you have two choices. The first is to convert the data to the required format yourself, possibly using some third-party library. The second one is to use *MediaRecorder* from the Android library. Unfortunately, it supports only writing to a file-like destination, so you cannot simply replace *AudioRecorder* with it, but there's a workaround described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320691/android-mediarecorder-in-streaming).